# How do I lock only one layer axis when scaling a group in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I've made an Apple based window with live shapes in a group.

[image: AppleGroup]

And I want to to be able to scale the window up without scaling the top bar vertically but scaling horizontally like the image in the back

[image: AppleOverSizedTopBar]

I've read that photoshop doesn't have nine-slice scaling but i was wondering if I can just constrain the y axis on the top grey bar when I try to scale it out

Comment: If you constrain the y axis your buttons and corners will be stretched. I'm not sure you can easily do this in Photoshop.

Comment: Nah cause i'll just group the white and topbar again, and use that group for scale, and use the top group for translations. The corners won't be stretched cause they are all smart objects anyways. If I could constrain the y axis i'd pretty much get what i'd need, If I figure something out i'll post it

Comment: Your shapes in your screenshots are shape layers, not smart objects.. do you mean they are live shapes rather than smart objects?

Comment: yeah! lol my mistake, you are totally right! They are shape layers xD I was thinking of 'vector' objects over smart objects.. But anyways you are right, they are shape layers.

Comment: What do you need this for? It cannot be done in Photoshop to my knowledge but I can think of a few alternatives that might help you depending on the need.

Comment: I was just making sure there were no secret tools in photoshop that I may have missed out on, and honestly it was just to play around in photoshop, was probably going to just give it away as mock up content or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly what you are asking for in Photoshop but I have a workaround which *may* be helpful.

Create a new document bigger than you will ever need your window to be. I created one at 4000 x 4000 pixels. Recreate your application frame in this document without any space around it or drop shadow. Select all and go to **Edit → Define Pattern...**

[image]

Back in your original document, create your live rectangle, add a layer style with your drop shadow and your newly created pattern as a pattern fill and hit the **Snap to Origin** button. You can now move and resize your 'window' and the top bar will stay in place.

[image]

This isn't perfect, obviously your pattern isn't easily editable but you can save it as its own PSD and recreate the pattern as needed.

Another option is to use the same trick with an oversized window but place it as a Smart Object and use a mask to create the shape. This makes editing the window much easier but all resizing would need to be done on the mask.

Comment: This is super great! i would have never thought of this, even though it seems now like such an obvious solution! Great Work! Thank you very much